# Can i host my custom node server on firebase rather than heroku?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following app model ,
Client side firebase , cloud functions , and minimal node js server for some
Custom actions, I am currently using heroku , but to be honest I don’t want to use 1000 services I want it all to be at one place , please note that I am serving my react app statically using the mentioned server .. could this be possible to achieve ? I don’t want to refactor my node logic just drag and drop in to firebase if possible ..

Comment: It's not possible to run a standard nodejs server on any Firebase product.  You can certainly use Cloud Functions to host specific API endpoints, but it won't be a traditional nodejs server.

Comment: well if I have to run cloud function each time I will have to serve my app, then the cost will go to the moon.

Comment: You're only supposed to use Cloud Functions when backend processing is needed.  You can serve static web assets using Firebase Hosting for very little cost.

Comment: so technically if I make my node js logic cloud functions compatible I can ditch Heroku and go only firebase serving my react app, thanks , I will check the case and do a study... might be better than staying on Heroku.

Comment: You might also consider other alternatives like Adaptable.io or Render.com. Both have free tiers.